# Storing Data Locally in Python

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm running a Scrapy project and I'm looking for the best method for storing already scraped data locally. Currently I'm using `AnyDBM` but i keep getting the following error after a while of running:

`bsddb.db.DBRunRecoveryError: (-30973, 'DB_RUNRECOVERY: Fatal error, run database recovery -- PANIC: fatal region error detected; run recovery')`

It my be something I'm doing wrong as I'm pretty new to Python, but i was wondering if there is a better solution other than Anydbm anyway.

I'm storing numeric ID's of the pages I have crawled, and will be storing around 500,000 records with plans for a possible 3-4 million for future projects.

Is AnyDBM what i should be sticking with or should i change to something more suitable for the job.

Comment: Are you using / planning on using multiple threads / processes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default python comes with [`sqlite3`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) which is a very good data base system.

Here is a [pretty good tutorial](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/07/18/python-a-simple-step-by-step-sqlite-tutorial/) on it. To put the table in memory use:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
conn.isolation_level = None
cur = conn.cursor()
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a good fit for [`sqlite`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html), already part of Python's standard library.